How to prevent a paste in a cell with carriage returns from overwriting the values ​below?
In apps script, how to prevent pasting text in a cell (keyboard shortcuts) with carriage returns from overwriting the values ​​below?
I tried a onedit(e) function, but we cannot intercept keyboard events, nor even with an onchange(e) function.

From what I know, there's no direct way to prevent pasting text in a cell (keyboard shortcuts) with carriage returns from overwriting the values in a spreadsheet. Aside from @TheMaster's recommendation, I found this Stack Overflow post to have a similar issue as yours. However, it uses data validation. Another workaround that you may consider is creating a script that protects the cells that have data so that users won't be able to paste anything into them.

Before pasting, click Enter to go into the cell you're pasting to and then use the paste keyboard shortcut.

Yes indeed, but that does not prevent users from making a copy sticking inadvertently as it happens sometimes.
At least, I can display a message and put "attention crushed" in the affected cells , the oldvalue value is not accessible which if effectively we type enter in the cell.
THANKS

@ericire Another complicated method is just to save a version of all values in the sheet every 5 minutes or so in the Script Cache and revert back, when you detect paste. Not sure about the reliability or usefulness, but that is one option to consider, if you're really worried. Personally, I believe teaching them undo(CTRL Z) should be more than enough since we always have a  inbuilt version history(Note that this is not readily accessible with scripts)

Google Sheets and Google Apps Script don't have built-in ways to know how the user uses the Google Sheets UI to edit a spreadsheet.
The best that a "developer" can do using Google Apps Script is to identify how many cells were edited at once. If more than one cell was edited using the Google Sheets UI, it's most likely that this was done using paste. You might use the edit trigger to know how many cells were edited and then do something about it. The edit event properties include helpful data, and the missing details, like the sheet edited, can be obtained using the Spreadsheet Service or the Advanced Sheets Service.
One option is to show a dialog and ask the user to undo the change. Another option is to revert the change done by the user automatically. The complexity of this task might vary.
Design a Solution
Things to consider when designing a solution based on Google Apps Script
Ask the user to undo
The user can make use of the File > Edit > Undo , Ctrl + z or  Command + z to undo the change done. An on-edit trigger might be used to ask the user to use undo.
Showing a toast
This is the less intrusive way to show a message to the user.
Showing an alert
The script execution will be paused until the user dismisses the alert or the execution time is exceeded.
Showing a dialog (HTML Service)
The script will continue to execute after the dialog is shown. google.script.run might be used to call a server-side function from the dialog, i.e., having a button to let the user revert the change using a "backup" (see the next element), but not to call undo.
Reverting the change done by the user.
There isn't a built-in way to call undo, so the revert requires a place to read the previous values and cell formatting. Unfortunately, the file history is not easily reached.
